# save image to desktop

Tags: java, jquery, image, save

I have a website written in java which displays an image on its homepage. I need to provide an interface to the user which allows them to save this image on their desktop via an floppy icon placed next to it. Can you please let me know how to do this

Comment: Is it really necessary to clutter the page with such a useless icon? All browsers I know support right-click -> save image as...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really need is the correct response header. Like so.

```
reponse.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                  "attachment; filename=" +
                  "Example.png");
```

And then I would try to doing

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/images/background.png").forward(request,response);
```

But I haven't actually tested this so you may have to read the file and copy the `bytes` instead. :(

Comment: If I set the Content-disposition header, wouldn't it affect my actual image which is getting displayed on the browser. I would not like that image to get disturbed. That image should be displayed on the browser, but the save link should allow to save the image

Comment: No. The above code is only for the download button. You should change the header when you set download=true. This way the existing code will not be affected.

Comment: Thanks Amir. I am actually using a href tag linked to this image to allow downloading the image. How can I change the header using a href tag?

Comment: Make the href point to /download?file=/images/background.jpg and then do the above in download servlet.

Comment: what I understand is, I need to create a new servlet e.g. download & set the headers in it right? Please correct me if I am wrong or anything else has to be written in the servlet

Comment: That is correct. Then just read the 'file' parameter and forward to that file. Try it first and post some more code.

Comment: In my jsp I put <a href="Download?file=images/output.png">Download here</a>

Comment: in download servlet, I just wrote this part response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" +
                "output.png" );

Comment: I am getting the dialog box now, but the image which is saved is an blank image. Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Can you post your code please? You need to forward to the image.

Comment: I wrote the bytestream to the servlet & got it to work. Thanks so much Amir. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Yup, marked it as right answer. One last question. My app generates the image based upon some user input text, saves it to a temp location & then displayed on the browser. Since this temp location is common to all the users, its quite possible that when other user tries to save the image, it may pick up the image generated for the 1st user. So my question is, is it possible to save this image in session object, so that images are specific to that user session only? Please guide

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can store the bytes as byte[]. If you are displaying this only once then store it in memory and print the bytes as images. If you need to display it multiple times then your session idea is good. You can also use File.createTempFile() to create a random temporary file that should be unique each time.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you need to stream the binary from the server with the correct content type + disposition set

This URL will point you in the right direction

http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip94.html